# Delete complex object graph from EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to delete an object graph from EF, but everything I try throws an error:

```
var dbSet = _context.Set(typeof (MyObject));
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

When I do that, it says my object doesn't exist in the ObjectManager.

So then I read I need to attach it first.  So I try this:

```
 var dbSet = _context.Set(typeof (MyObject));
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

But that blows up during the attach part saying attaching failed failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happened to `_context` before the code you show here? What is its lifespan?

Comment: It's created in the ctor of my UnitOfWork Class. That class is created and disposed for every call to either Insert a new Record or Update.

Comment: And is this all that you do with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have retrieved your entity from the database already using the same context then why not simply use

```
_context.MyObject.Remove(entity);
```

The entity must have been sourced from the same context instance as the one you are using to remove (unless you are attaching/detaching).

Alternatively do something like:

```
_context.MyObject.Remove(_context.MyObject.Find(id));
_context.SaveChanges();
```

In addition, although this isn't what your problem is, you need to manage the cascading deletions where database constraints exist. Unless you have your DB set to manage those cascading deletes for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using GraphDiff for this. It worked well.